# A RegionPlot bug in v11.2

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.2. Fixed in 12.2.0 or earlier.**

---

```
Ω = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}], 
   Rectangle[{40, 40}, {60, 60}]];
RegionPlot[Ω]

DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

when I run it in v11.2 I got

[image]

while I run it in v11 I got

[image]

so is it a bug?

Comment: (Please only use the [tag:bugs] tag for bugs confirmed by the community. Read the tag info page for more details)

Comment: (observation: note the "0..2" labels on the axes. The data is correct, the PlotRange detection is unexpected)

Comment: @user202729 yes,the range is different ,but in v11 it runs out the correct range automaticly so in v11.2 we should operate mannually?

Comment: @user202729 also we can use the RegionPlot rather than DensityPlot so we must set the range mannually?

Comment: I consider it a bug. A workaround is `RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega], PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}]` and `DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, f}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon i would like ti.know your version ,is it true that version higher than v11.0 have this bug?

Comment: I see the problem with v11.2 and v11.3 but not with v11.1 (on a Mac)

Comment: @BobHanlon ok,acknowledge it and thanks a lot!

Comment: As a workaround, how about `\[CapitalOmega] = 
  DiscretizeRegion@
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}], 
    Rectangle[{40, 40}, {60, 60}]];`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher we can use this function every time using RegionPlot,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** according to the comment by @kirma it is fixed already since `12.2`

Update from `13.2.0`

With

```
Ω = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}], 
   Rectangle[{40, 40}, {60, 60}]];
RegionPlot[Ω]
DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} ∈ \[CapitalOmega]]
```

we get

> [image: pp1]

> [image: pp2]

Comment: This also seems to work on v12.2, might have been fixed even earlier...

Comment: @kirma I just saw you updated the bugs header. Thanks a lot for that and for letting me know!